# How can I add a key to a element?

Tags: c#, xml

I write an element in an XML file using XmlWriter

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.x))
{
   writer.WriteStartElement("Order");
   writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

which writes the following to the file

```
<Order>
</Order>
```

However, I want to write the following

```
<Order key="Name">
</Order>
```

[WriteStartElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t5yhhk.aspx) only takes one argument:

```
public void WriteStartElement(
string localName
)
```

So I guess I have to use a different function, but I can't find which one. So ho can I add a key to an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an attribute named `key` (since that's what you seem to want to add - an attribute to the `Order` element):

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.x))
{
   writer.WriteStartElement("Order");
   writer.WriteAttributeString("key", "value");
   writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

See [`WriteAttributeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring.aspx).